# Extract audio from a folder of mp4 videos

Tags: macos, audio, video, file-conversion, encoding

Any good apps/tools for OSX that will convert an entire folder of mp4 videos into audio files?

Comment: If the answers in the linked question (and in similar ones displayed in the "Related" column at the right hand side) don't work for you, please edit your question to explain what you have tried and where it doesn't work as required.

Comment: I am looking for an app that works on an entire folder

Comment: There probably isn't a ready-to-use solution, but it should be possible to do some shell scripting e.g. based on the accepted answer to the question linked to on top. If this is what you need, please **edit your question text** accordingly.